# How to represent given adjacency matrix as undirected weighted graph in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph

For below given matrix,how it can be represented as undirected weighted graph G(V,E,W) where V is set of vertices,E is set of edges and W is set of weights.

```
  4     2     3     1     4
  2     2     3     1     4
  2     3     3     1     4
  1     2     3     1     4
  4     2     3     1     5
```

Source code i tried:

```
%table2 is given matrix
bg = biograph(table2,[],'ShowArrows','off','ShowWeights','on');
h = view(bg);
```

Is this the right way to represent undirected weighted graph for my matrix?Iam getting 2 edges between same 2 verteces.Just like this

[image]

I got this output for your suggested code
[image]

Iam having 2 adjacency matrices.I have to perform below 2 operations:

1.I have to make 2 graphs from these 2 adjacency matrices.

2.Then i have to match vertices of 2 graphs depending on weights of edges in graph.

```
  4     2     3     1     4
  2     2     3     1     4
  2     3     3     1     4
  1     2     3     1     4
  4     2     3     1     5

 4     1     3     2     4
 1     1     2     3     4
 3     1     3     2     4
 2     1     3     2     4
 4     1     3     2     5
```

The way iam going is right or wrong?Please suggest me

Comment: What do you get when you try it? And if you want a weighted graph, why do you have `'ShowWeights','off'`?

Comment: Sorry its 'ShowWeights','on'

Comment: Iam getting 2 edges between same 2 vertex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get only one edge between each vertex, you only want a triangular matrix.

If you try something like this:

```
table1 = (table2 + table2') - triu((table2 + table2')) 
table1 =
     0     0     0     0     0
     4     0     0     0     0
     5     6     0     0     0
     2     3     4     0     0
     8     6     7     5     0

bg = biograph(table1,[],'ShowArrows','off','ShowWeights','on');
h = view(bg);
```

Now I have assumed you want to sum up the weights from both edges. I.e. the weight of the edge between 1-2 equal the weight of the edge from 1->2 + 2->1, from your original matrix.
[image]